Can you get more than 21 years prison in total in Norway for the sum of two completely unrelated crimes?
This should go without saying, but I'm asking this out of sheer curiosity, not for any practical reasons lol.
The maximum prison time one can get for any particular crime in Norway is 21 years. This also applies if one murders multiple people, etc.
However, what if there's multiple completely unrelated crimes, in different jurisdictions? Let's say someone commits a cold blooded murder in Oslo that warrants 21 years of prison, then, before they're arrested, travels to the other end of the country and steals a car, damages property and commits insurance fraud? Can they then get 21 years for the murder they committed in Oslo and more years on top of that for the rest, or can they get no more time since they already hit the cap with the murder?

I don't know how this is handled in Norway, but since the crimes are unrelated and have been committed in two different provinces, I would assume that there will also two separate trials. And it would be strange if the second court had to aquit him just because he already got a lifetime sentence elsewhere.

@PMF, in Germany the second court would calculate a "compounded sentence" out of the two separate outcomes, which would be capped at 15 years if none of them is a life sentence. These compounding rules apply both for multiple sentences in one trial, and successive trials (Nachträgliche Gesamtstrafenbildung).

@PMF in no instance would an acquittal make sense; the most extreme result would be conviction in the second case with sentences to be served concurrently, resulting in no prison time added to the sentence imposed in the first case.  Acquittal would mean that if the first verdict were subsequently overturned on appeal, or nullified for any other reason, the offender would have to be released.  A concurrent sentence (and presumably a compound sentence as mentioned by o.m.) means that the second conviction continues to have effect if the first is somehow undone.

@phoog So if the statute of limitations allows, perhaps the best prosecution strategy is to defer the second trial until you finish your first sentence? Of course, that runs the risk that witnesses may forget, evidence goes missing, etc.

I would sincerely hope that after having served the maximum sentence for Crime 1, that you are not completely off the hook for new crimes that you commit.

@BartvanIngenSchenau You mean crimes you commited prior to or after the sentence?

@Fiksdal, I meant crimes you commit after having been released from prison. For example, I commit murder, serve 21 years and after that advertise my services as a hit-man.

@BartvanIngenSchenau In that case you can 100% get more prison time.
